# localStorage and updateView + windows 8

Tags: windows-8, local-storage, windows-store-apps, winjs

I have some items and I mark them as favorite by pressing a button, here is the code:

```
function AddToFavorites() {
    //called when a shop is added as as a favorite one.
    //first we check if already is favorite
    var favoritesArray = getStoreArray();
    var alreadyExists = exists();
    if (!alreadyExists) {
        favoritesArray.push(itemHolder);
        var storage = window.localStorage;
        storage.shopsFavorites = JSON.stringify(favoritesArray);
    }   
}

function exists() {
    var alreadyExists = false;
    var favoritesArray = getStoreArray();
    for (var key in favoritesArray) {
        if (favoritesArray[key].title == itemHolder.title) {
            //already exists
            alreadyExists = true;
        }
    }
    return alreadyExists;
}

function getStoreArray() {
    //restores our favorites array if any or creates one
    var storage = window.localStorage;
    var favoritesArray = storage.shopsFavorites;
    if (favoritesArray == null || favoritesArray == "") {
        //if first time
        favoritesArray = new Array();
    } else {
        //if there are already favorites
        favoritesArray = JSON.parse(favoritesArray);
    }
    return favoritesArray;
}
```

And I have a favorites.html to present those as a list.
The problem I have is that the list doesn't update automaticly every time I add or remove items.

Here is my code for that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Αγαπημένα</title>

    <!-- WinJS references -->
    <link href="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/css/ui-dark.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/js/base.js"></script>
    <script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/js/ui.js"></script>

    <link href="favoritesDetails.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="favoritesDetails.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="favoritesDetails fragment">
        <header aria-label="Header content" role="banner">
            <button class="win-backbutton" aria-label="Back" disabled type="button"></button>
            <h1 class="titlearea win-type-ellipsis">
                <span class="pagetitle">Αγαπημένα</span>
            </h1>
        </header>
        <section aria-label="Main content" role="main">
                <div id="mediumListIconTextTemplate" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template" style="display: none">
        <div class="mediumListIconTextItem">
            <img src="#" class="mediumListIconTextItem-Image" data-win-bind="src: picture" />
            <div class="mediumListIconTextItem-Detail">
                <h4 data-win-bind="innerText: title"></h4>
                <h6 data-win-bind="innerText: text"></h6>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="basicListView" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView" 
        data-win-options="{itemDataSource : DataExample.itemList.dataSource, 
            itemTemplate: select('#mediumListIconTextTemplate')}">
    </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the JavaScript code:

```
// For an introduction to the Page Control template, see the following documentation:
// http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=232511
var dataArray = [], shopsArray = [];

(function () {
    "use strict";

    var app = WinJS.Application;
    var activation = Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation;
    var nav = WinJS.Navigation;
    var ui = WinJS.UI;

    shopsArray = getStoreArray();
    if (shopsArray) {
        for (var key in shopsArray) {
            var group = { title: shopsArray[key].title, text: shopsArray[key].subtitle, picture: shopsArray[key].backgroundImage, description: shopsArray[key].description, phoneNumbers: shopsArray[key].content };
            dataArray.push(group);
        }
        var dataList = new WinJS.Binding.List(dataArray);

        // Create a namespace to make the data publicly
        // accessible. 
        var publicMembers =
            {
                itemList: dataList
            };
        WinJS.Namespace.define("DataExample", publicMembers);
    }

    WinJS.UI.Pages.define("/pages/favoritesDetails/favoritesDetails.html", {
        // This function is called whenever a user navigates to this page. It
        // populates the page elements with the app's data.

        ready: function (element, options) {
        },

        unload: function () {
        },

        updateLayout: function (element, viewState, lastViewState) {
        }    
    });
})();

function getStoreArray() {
    //restores our favorites array if any or creates one
    var storage = window.localStorage;
    var favoritesArray = storage.shopsFavorites;
    if (favoritesArray == null || favoritesArray == "") {
        //if first time
        favoritesArray = new Array();
    } else {
        //if there are already favorites
        favoritesArray = JSON.parse(favoritesArray);
    }
    return favoritesArray;
}
```

So how can I update the favorites HTML page when new favorites are stored/removed in the localDB? can i add event listeners there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the code that stores favorites a part of the same app?

If so, I would consider adding the favorite to the underlying WinJS.Binding.list that you're using to bind to the ListView, and then store the updated list info in the DB, rather than trying to react to changes in the DB from the ListView.

Have a look at the following sample, which shows how to update a ListView dynamically:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/ListView-custom-data-4dcfb128/sourcecode?fileId=50893&pathId=1976562066

Hope that helps!